UMVUE for the Product of Means from Independent Samples
Let $ x_1, \ldots, x_m $ be i.i.d. samples drawn from a distribution $P$, and $ y_1, \ldots, y_n $ be i.i.d. samples drawn from a distribution $Q$. Assume that the samples $x_i$ and $y_j$ are independent of each other. Suppose $\bar{X}$ is the uniform minimum variance unbiased estimator (UMVUE) for $\mu_X = E_{X \sim P}[X]$ and $\bar{Y}$ is the UMVUE for $\mu_Y = E_{Y \sim Q}[Y]$.
What is the UMVUE for the parameter $\mu_X \mu_Y$? Is $\bar{X} \bar{Y}$ the UMVUE for $\mu_X \mu_Y$, or is there a better estimator?

There is in general no reason that $\bar{X} \bar{Y}$ have expectation $\mu_X  \mu_Y$ ...

$x_i$ and $y_j$ are assumed independent so $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are independent hence $\bar{X}\bar{Y}$ will have expectation $\mu_X \mu_Y$.

Thanks, missed that. Do you know something more, like distributions, or if $\bar{X}, \bar{Y}$ are sufficient, complete?

No, we don't know much about distributions. so I'm happy to know of any counterexample as well.
